# ionic Native DocumentViewer did not work in Android

Tags: ionic-framework, documentviewer

In ionic , Native DocumentViewer did not work in Android , when i downloaded it and opened in ios using this native documentviewer  it woked. is there any problem in with documentviewer in ionic documentation?

Comment: Might be i remember there is issue with local file or live file path

Answer (score 0):

Documentviewer is not working in android(tested in 6.0 and 7.0) i have tested with my application(requires pdf reader) it asks to download another app from playstore when we call the documentviewer.

so i went for an alternative from angular [link](https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/)

[repo link](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer)

**note**: performance of this plugin not so good for large pdfs.